# AdLDAP -- Failed testing the authentication. Is it essentially need SSL?

Tags: php, ldap, adldap

I'm testing the AdLDAP Library with my PHP. As i'm a new to LDAP overall, i'm not sure what is wrong.

This is how i initiated the class:

```
$adldap = new adLDAP( array(
    'base_dn'=>'DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=sg',
    'account_suffix'=>'@xxxx.xxxx.sg',
    'domain_controllers'=>array('ns01.xxxx.xxxx.sg','dc02.xxxx.xxxx.sg'),
    'ad_port'=>389,
    'use_tls'=>true
));
```

Then when i test the `Authentication` sample, it always saying `"Failed!"`.
One only thing is that our Server does **NOT using SSL**.
Is it the factor?
OR
What other else is getting wrong (or) needing to be checked?

Comment: `One only thing is that our Server does NOT using SSL.` - why do you have `'use_tls'=>true` then?

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct, TLS uses port 389, SSL uses 636.

It would appear you have the correct settings for TLS but your server isn't configured for it.
Maybe its configured for SSL only.

Answer (score -1):

If you use TLS, the default port is 636.